# How do I install mate-screenshot?

Tags: software-installation, mate, screenshot

How do I install `mate-screenshot`?

I have installed standard MATE from repositories on an Ubuntu 16.04 LTS system, this way:

```
sudo apt install mate-desktop
```

at this point, the option to select MATE at the cog in the greeter did not appear, so I had to run

```
sudo apt install mate-session-manager
```

after which MATE did appear at the cog in the greeter.

Now, when I press <kbd>Print Screen</kbd> to take a picture of system menu, nothing happens. If I don't open a system menu, a modal dialog opens saying

> There was an error running mate-screenshot: Failed to execute child process "mate-screenshot" (No such file or directory)

I have tried running

```
sudo apt install mate-screenshot
```

but it says

```
E: Unable to locate package mate-screenshot
```

How do I install it?

MATE version 1.12.1-1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`mate-screenshot` is from the [`mate-utils` package](https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/mate-utils). So install `mate-utils` by running the following command in Terminal:

```
sudo apt install mate-utils
```

Answer (score 0):

Debian 12 recent release.
Completed the following two steps:

1. `sudo apt install mate-utils`
2. `sudo apt install mate-screenshot`

However,same message: "Unable to locate package mate-screenshot"

UPDATE: It works now, I do not know what happened, since it failed initially I did install Shutter and Screenshot from the software catalog. Now, suddenly, the app TAKE SCREENSHOT is there and working fine. I have removed the others.